# Update table using another table "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Tags: postgresql

**ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**
I have temporary table temp_marks with key and value as column.
I am trying to update the student_subject table with temp_mark.

```
UPDATE student_subjects
set marks = (SELECT tmp.value 
             FROM temp_marks AS tmp )::int
WHERE student_id = std_id 
  AND subject_id IN (select id 
                     from subjects 
                     where code in (SELECT key FROM temp_marks)
                    );
```

Comment: That error means that there is more than one row in the `temp_marks` table.

Comment: Simply add a `LIMIT 1` to the first subquery.

Comment: how do we update a single field from multiple rows? I want to update multiple field in student_subject table from temp_mark